# put background color on slot time of vaadin calendar

Tags: java, colors, calendar, vaadin

I would like to put background colors on Vaadin calendar. 
This color should be different depending on the time: 
eg : daily between 8am and 12pm: green background, 
daily between 12h and 14h: blue background, ...

I don't find a solution. 
Is it possible?

Comment: DID you mean putting color of calender event or you asking about color of time slots in daily view?

Comment: I speak about color of time slots in daily view, not about color of an event.

Comment: I think that is not possible unless until you modify underlying widget of calender.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Vaadin `DateCell` class and add additional stylenames for different ranges (`DateCell:127`).

So then you can define any style you need for it.